# Ruby Selenium Web Driver: How to find child element by class name matching substring

Tags: ruby, selenium, svg, xpath

Am a novice selenium programmer please help me with this...

I have below html and am trying to find `svg` child element by class name matching substring `deleteIcon` in below html

```
<div class="result-controls">
   <div class="attachment">
      <li class="add-attachment-button-column"><a><button>ADD ATTACHMENTS</button></a></li><input type="file" multiple="" style="display: none;">
   </div>
   <li class="sign-button-column"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><button>SIGN</button></a></li>
   <li class="draft-button-column"><a><button>DRAFT</button></a></li>
   <li class="delete-column"> <a href="javascript:void(0)"><svg class="glyphicon-trash deleteIcon" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#trash"></use></svg> </a></li>
</div>
```

I am trying to find `svg` element class matching 'deleteIcon' (`row` variable has above html)

```
  row.find_element(:xpath => "./li/a/svg[contains(@class,'deleteIcon')]")
```

but am getting below exception

```
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=./li/a/svg[contains(@class,'deleteIcon')]} (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException)
```

can anyone help me with this in Ruby using selenium web driver?

Comment: The `svg` you posted has class 'glyphicon-trash', so it doesn't contain 'deleteIcon'... and I can't find string 'deleteIcon' anywhere in the HTML above

Comment: mybad, just updated the question with deleteIcon class in svg element

Comment: Then your XPath should've worked, assuming `row` variable correctly referenced the outer `div`. Maybe try to simplify your XPath and see if it return something now : `//svg[contains(@class,'deleteIcon')]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `svg` as a tag name in xpath expression.Try using below xpath,

```
"./li/a/*[name()='svg'][contains(@class,'deleteIcon')]"
```

Comment: @sudharshan Thanks for the answer, can you also help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43385291/ruby-selenium-web-drive-how-to-find-specific-element-by-xpath-div-id-and-css-cl

Comment: sure! if my above answer helped you consider accepting it!