# Ruby Selenium Web Drive: How to find specific element by xpath div id and css class

Tags: ruby, selenium, xpath

I have a below html which am trying to test using ruby selenium web driver

```
<div class="container-fluid container-results">
    <div class="result-row" id="0">
        <ul>
            <li class="process-status-column upload-success-icon">
                <svg class="glyphicon-upload-green" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
                    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#doc_upload"></use>
                </svg>
            </li>
            <li class="file-label-column"><span>validated.txt</span></li>
            <li class="client-company-column"><span>test-client</span></li>
            <li class="reference-column"><span>Ref001</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="result-row" id="1">
        <ul>
            <li class="process-status-column upload-error-icon">
                <svg class="glyphicon-exclamation" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
                    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#exclamation"></use>
                </svg>
            </li>
            <li class="file-label-column"><span>Error.txt</span>
                <div class="attachment-row">This invoice contains an error</div>
            </li>
            <li class="client-company-column"><span>test-client</span></li>
            <li class="reference-column"><span>Ref002</span></li>            
        </ul>
    </div>   
    <div class="result-row" id="2">
        <ul>
            <li class="process-status-column upload-pending-icon">
                <svg class="glyphicon-spin" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
                    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#refresh"></use>
                </svg>
            </li>
            <li class="file-label-column"><span>Pending.txt</span></li>
            <li class="client-company-column"></li>
            <li class="reference-column"></li>            
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to find the `svg` element of any given `div` id as below in Ruby using selenium web driver

```
    rows = driver.find_elements(:css => "div.container-fluid.container-results >div\##{row_number.to_i-1} >ul >li >a >svg")
```

But I am getting below exception when am running the script with row number 1

```
    invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
  (Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.133)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 25 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html

Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver

*** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=div.container-fluid.container-results >div#0 >ul >li >a >svg} (org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException)
[remote server] sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor17():-1:in `newInstance'
[remote server] sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl():-1:in `newInstance'
[remote server] java.lang.reflect.Constructor():-1:in `newInstance'
[remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler(ErrorHandler.java):206:in `createThrowable'
[remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler(ErrorHandler.java):158:in `throwIfResponseFailed'
[remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver(RemoteWebDriver.java):678:in `execute'
[remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver(RemoteWebDriver.java):388:in `findElements'
[remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver(RemoteWebDriver.java):496:in `findElementsByCssSelector'
[remote server] org.openqa.selenium.By$ByCssSelector(By.java):441:in `findElements'
[remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver(RemoteWebDriver.java):351:in `findElements'
[remote server] sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19():-1:in `invoke'
[remote server] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl():-1:in `invoke'
[remote server] java.lang.reflect.Method():-1:in `invoke'
[remote server] org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$2(EventFiringWebDriver.java):103:in `invoke'
[remote server] com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1():-1:in `findElements'
[remote server] org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver(EventFiringWebDriver.java):177:in `findElements'
[remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.FindElements(FindElements.java):50:in `call'
[remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.FindElements(FindElements.java):1:in `call'
[remote server] java.util.concurrent.FutureTask():-1:in `run'
[remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1(DefaultSession.java):176:in `run'
[remote server] java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor():-1:in `runWorker'
[remote server] java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker():-1:in `run'
[remote server] java.lang.Thread():-1:in `run'
```

If I try running `$("div.container-fluid.container-results >div#0 >ul >li >a >svg")` in my browser console I do see the `svg` elements but its not working from Ruby, can someone please help me with this?

Comment: You are using invalid css selector. can you try this one, `div.container-fluid.container-results > div.result-row[id]  svg`

Comment: @SudharsanSelvaraj still getting the same `invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified *** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=div.container-fluid.container-results > div.result-row[0] svg} (org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException)`

Comment: use the exact locator which I have mentioned. do not replace `result-row[id]` to `result-row[0]`

Comment: @SudharsanSelvaraj tried it, still failing

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to find the svg element of any given div id

If this is what you want, you can try this one:

```
driver.find_element(:id => "the_given_id").find_elements(:tag_name => "svg")
```

Comment: I want to find all the `svg` elements inside the `div class="result-row"` there can be multiple `svg` elements, in this context there is only one..

Comment: I have updated my answer, instead of find_element, you use find_elements

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Selenium documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/0.0.28/Selenium/WebDriver/Find) `:css` is not a valid selector for `find_elements`.

It specified `:class, :class_name, :id, :link_text, :link, :partial_link_text, :name, :tag_name, :xpath` to be valid selectors.

The `:css` selector do still work in many situations, however it does not always work as you would expect. For example would `div.container-fluid.container-results > div#0` be invalid for selenium, even tho it is valid for the browsers.

You could use xpath or some of the other selectors to get the svg.

If you want to use the css selector to find it, you could use nokogiri, here is an example:

```
selenium_driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
selenium_driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/")

# do whatever with selenium

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(selenium_driver.page_source)
doc.css("div.container-fluid.container-results >div##{row_number.to_i-1} >ul >li >a >svg")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying a lot of levels in the CSS selector. From the HTML you posted, it doesn't look like you need them all. Using `>` in a CSS selector specifies a child where using a space signifies any descendant. Any `SVG` descendant of the `DIV` should work. You should be able to use just this

```
rows = driver.find_elements(:css => "div.container-fluid.container-results svg")
```